# How to join three tables with group concat in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, join

I am trying to join three tables with group concat.Problem is main tables have joining column in json format.

Query is working but repeating the joining column data again and again
query ->

```
[SELECT tour_package.description AS description, 
         tour_package.NAME AS NAME, 
         GROUP_CONCAT( destination_continent.NAME ) AS continent_name,
         GROUP_CONCAT( travel_style.NAME ) AS travel_style_name,
         tour_package.id AS id, 
         tour_package.img_path_thumb AS img_path_thumb, 
         tour_package.continent_id, 
         tour_package.travel_style_id
FROM tour_package
LEFT JOIN destination_continent ON 
      FIND_IN_SET( destination_continent.id, 
           REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( tour_package.continent_id,  '\[',  '' ) ,  '\]',  '' ) ,  '\"',  '' ) ) 
LEFT JOIN travel_style ON 
      FIND_IN_SET( travel_style.id, 
           REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( tour_package.travel_style_id,  '\[',  '' ) ,  '\]',  '' ) ,  '\"',  '' ) ) 
WHERE  `tour_package`.`DELETE` = 0 &&  `destination_continent`.`DELETE` = 0
LIMIT 0 , 30][1]
```

Tables ->[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT keyword in  GROUP_CONCAT function

I.e:

```
SELECT tour_package.description AS description, 
       tour_package.NAME AS NAME, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT destination_continent.NAME ) AS continent_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT travel_style.NAME ) AS travel_style_name,
       tour_package.id AS id, 
       tour_package.img_path_thumb AS img_path_thumb, 
       tour_package.continent_id, 
       tour_package.travel_style_id
....
```

Comment: thnx, now i am laughing on my self, i have to take a tonic for memory

Answer (score 0):

While Group Concatenating do a `Distinct` check

```
[SELECT tour_package.description AS description, tour_package.NAME AS NAME, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT(destination_continent.NAME) ) AS continent_name, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT(travel_style.NAME) ) AS travel_style_name, tour_package.id AS id, tour_package.img_path_thumb AS img_path_thumb, tour_package.continent_id, tour_package.travel_style_id FROM tour_package LEFT JOIN destination_continent ON FIND_IN_SET( destination_continent.id, REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( tour_package.continent_id,  '\[',  '' ) ,  '\]',  '' ) ,  '\"',  '' ) )  LEFT JOIN travel_style ON FIND_IN_SET( travel_style.id, REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( tour_package.travel_style_id,  '\[',  '' ) ,  '\]',  '' ) ,  '\"',  '' ) )  WHERE  `tour_package`.`DELETE` =0 &&  `destination_continent`.`DELETE` =0 LIMIT 0 , 30][1]
```